# Adminhtml custom field - how to create one?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, custom, field

How to create a custom field in adminhtml form?
I can customize fields in grid but I need to add my own field (table) in form to be sortable.

Comment: custom form? or any specific core form?

Comment: Custom/Specific (cms/block) only, not every form :P

Comment: did you look at something like this article : http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/02/magento-admin-form-field/

or do you need something else?

Comment: Yes, I already checked it, these are only a basic field types. What I need is the way how can I make multiline sortable ...

Comment: or how to add custom element to the form

Comment: This is actually funny, as I already made something like this long time ago ..... then I just forgot ....https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215405/magento-1-9-custom-multiselect-field-renderer-how-to?noredirect=1#comment300711_215405